# How to run x11vnc with rawframebuffer coming from /dev/fb0 and capturing mouse events from /dev/input/event3?

Tags: linux, framebuffer, x11vnc

I have tried running x11vnc reading a raw framebuffer from /dev/fb0 in my linux embedded system. I am using weston fbdev backend so it writes to the framebuffer /dev/fb0. It works, but when I connect to the VNC server, using a VNC client, no mouse events are being captured. I have read the documentation at https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc and from what I understood I should run:

`x11vnc -rawfb /dev/fb0 - -pipeinput UINPUT:touch,direct_abs=/dev/input/event3 -input KMBCF,KMBCF`

But still it does not work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

It is valid to mention that I have tried using the VNC backend in Weston, but it had poor performance and it was consuming 100% of CPU, making it unpractical to be used.

Comment: ... wouldn't it be much easier to directly use a [VNC backend for Weston](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/weston/-/merge_requests/880)?

Comment: Yes, except the fact that the VNC backend in Weston has poor performance and is consuming 100% of CPU, making it unpractical to be used.